# C# FMOD playing from stream

Tags: c#, audio, stream, fmod

Can anyone help me on playing a file from a memorystream using FMOD or any other way?

So far i have this:
**Variables**

```
    private FMOD.System _fmod = null;
    private FMOD.Sound _sound = null;
    private FMOD.Channel _channel = null;
```

**Code**

```
        var file = File.ReadAllBytes("test.ogg");
        //MessageBox.Show("Bytes from file: " + file.Length);

        FMOD.Factory.System_Create(ref _fmod);

        var result = _fmod.init(2, FMOD.INITFLAGS.NORMAL, (IntPtr)null);
        if(result != FMOD.RESULT.OK) ShowError(result);

        var info = new FMOD.CREATESOUNDEXINFO();

        result = _fmod.createStream(file, MODE.CREATESTREAM, ref info,  ref _sound);
        if (result != RESULT.OK) ShowError(result);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi! May I ask how you were able to make fmodex.dll work in C#? I am having confusion regarding this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, sorry I was unable to make it work... In the end I used MP3 format for the sound files, as I was running out of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly I highly recommend you take a look at the "loadfrommemory" example that ships with FMOD (it has a C# version too). But to answer your question here:

1. You need to populate some members of the FMOD.CREATESOUNDEXINFO structure:

   info.cbsize = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
   info.length = file.Length;
2. You need to tell FMOD you are providing in-memory data with the OPENMEMORY flag:

   result = _fmod.createStream(file, MODE.CREATESTREAM | MODE.OPENMEMORY, ref info,  ref _sound);

That should be all you need to get going.

Comment: WOW< how did i not see the examples_csharp!!!??? You are an absolute saviour!!! wish i could give u all my points :P thanks for the help!!

Comment: :D :D :D :D :D :D you're a god :) i thought i will never get my music player which i need to make for my dissertation working!!! :) FMOD is great!!!

Comment: Hey thanks, this is working now, but i have another problem, if i only fill, lets say, 10% of the buffer, then start playing, then carry on filling the buffer, the sound stop playing once it reaches the 10% mark. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: By using MODE.OPENMEMORY you are telling FMOD to copy the data pointed to by 'file' into its internal buffers. You could use MODE.OPENMEMORY_POINT but there are better solutions for streaming such as user created sounds with read callbacks.